# laravel, скачка файла с сервера

Tags: php, laravel, маршрутизация

Скорее всего вопрос глупый, и косяк явно в роутах, но я не вижу где он
Генерирую столбы с имена файлами и ссылками на данный файл

```
$(row).empty().append('<a href="storage/attach_file/' + group_data + '">' + group_data + '</a>')
```

на выходе получается такая ссылка

```
<a href="storage/attach_file/code_1534190483.txt">code_1534190483.txt</a>
```

Дальше прописываю роут для обработки

```
Route::get('/storage/attach_file/{item}','CollectionPointController@download');
```

ну и сам контроллер

```
public function download($item)
{
return response()->download(public_path('/public/attach_file/'.$item));
}
```

Спасибо за понимание

Comment: Где находится `attach_file`?

Answer (score 0):

Генирация

```
$(row).empty().append('<a href="download/' + group_data + '">' + group_data + '</a>')
```

Маршрут

```
Route::get('/download/{file}','CollectionPointController@download');
```

Ну и сама обработка:

```
public function download($file_name)
{
$filePath= public_path(). '\storage\attach_file\\'.$file_name;
return response()->download($filePath);
}
```

В такой комбинации этот код заработал, может вы найдете ответ для себя